# Priority Queue for D* Lite

Tags: c++, algorithm, pathfinding, priority-queue

So, I needed a priority queue for D* lite and I wanted to know whether this is an acceptable implementation or not.

```
#ifndef BCC940D8_CEDF_4B76_8CE4_D8C9A4D1A787
#define BCC940D8_CEDF_4B76_8CE4_D8C9A4D1A787

#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include "Node.hpp"
#include "Key.hpp"


namespace Pathfinding::Datastructures
{
    class NodeComperator
    {
    public:
        bool operator() (const Node * lhs, const Node * rhs)
        {
            return lhs->key > rhs->key;
        }
    };

    class PriorityQueue final : public std::priority_queue<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, NodeComperator>
    {
    public:
        void remove(Node *node)
        {
            auto it = std::find_if(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), 
            
                [&node](const Node * element)
                { 
                    return *element == *node; 
                });

            this->c.erase(it);
            std::make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
        }

        void insert(Node *node)
        {
            this->push(node);
        }

        void reset()
        {
            c.clear();
            std::make_heap(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), this->comp);
        }

        Key topKey() const
        {
            if (this->empty())
            {
                return Key();
            }
            return this->top()->key;
        }

        Node *popD()
        {
            auto topNode = this->top();
            pop();
            return topNode;
        }

        bool contains(const Node *node)
        {
            return std::find_if(this->c.begin(), this->c.end(), 
            [&node](const Node* input)
            { 
                return *input == *node; 
            }) != this->c.end();
        }

    private:
        using std::priority_queue<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, NodeComperator>::pop;
    };
}

#endif /* BCC940D8_CEDF_4B76_8CE4_D8C9A4D1A787 */
```

Nodes are sorted by key which is a tuple with two floats. "Keys are compared according to a lexicographic-ordering".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Unnecessary use of `this->`

It is almost never necessary to use `this->` in C++. I recommend you remove all occurrences of it in your code.

## Unnecessary call to `std::make_heap()`

It is not necessary to call `std::make_heap()` after clearing the underlying container.

## Naming things

I would rename `remove()` to `erase()`, as the `remove()` function in STL does mean something different than erasing.

`insert()` is just equivalent to `push()`. I would recommend removing `insert()`, and just let the caller use `push()` instead, which is publicly inherited.

`popD()` looks weird. I would just rename this to `pop()`; it will give you the functionality you want, and in a way it's still compatible with the STL's `pop()`.

## Missing `const`

`contains()` does not modify the queue, so it should be made `const`. Furthermore, `remove()` doesn't modify `node`, so you should make that parameter a `const` pointer.

## Use `std::find()` to find a specific node

You can use `std::find` to find a specific value without needing a lambda:

```
bool contains(const Node *node) const {
    return std::find(c.begin(), c.end(), node) != c.end();
}
```

## Simplifications possible using C++20

If you can use C++20, you can simplify your code somewhat. There are [`std::ranges` versions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges) of some of the algorithms, and you can use [`std::erase()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) to remove an item from the underlying vector by value. So for example, you could write:

```
void erase(const Node *node) {
    std::erase(c, node);
    std::ranges::make_heap(c);
}
```

Unfortunately there is no `std::contains()` in C++20, and it seems there won't even be any in C++23.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Pseudocode of the algorithm used this naming for methods, I kept it for easier understanding. Also, I don't think I can rename popD to pop because this function is already present in the base class and since it is not virtual, it is not overwritten, but yeah, popD is a bad name.

Comment: It will be overwritten in the derived class, and you can have the derived class call `pop()` of the base class by doing something like: `using base = std::priority_queue<Node *, std::vector<Node *>, NodeComperator>; ...; base::pop();`